Sub-ADC Circuit for Pipeline ADC
I am simulating the following Sub-ADC circuit which is intended to be used in a pipeline ADC.

The following is my simulation result at nodes VIP, VIN and CMP+. I applied ramps at VIP and VIN in an attempt to see the input-output characteristic of the sub-ADC circuit.

However, I noticed that node CMP+ is quite 'noisy', as shown in the zoomed-in picture.

Is there a way to make this node less 'noisy' so that the comparator may have less chance to produce incorrect outputs.
Thank you very much
